# problem with rosmaking mrpt_common package

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and installed ros-electric
I downloaded the mrpt_common package with folloeing script

```
  svn co http://mrpt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mrpt_common
```

and rosmake it.

However, error occurred.

```
  bcddivad@bcddivad-desktop:~/code/ros/MRPT/mrpt_common$ rosmake
  [ rosmake ] No package or stack specified.  And current directory 'mrpt_common' is not a package name or stack name.                                                                                           
  [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: []                                                                                                                                                                         
  [ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/bcddivad/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120622-201855                                                                                                                     
  [ rosmake ] Expanded args [] to:
  []                                                                                                                                                                            
  [ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.                                                                                                                             
  bcddivad@bcddivad-desktop:~/code/ros/MRPT/mrpt_common$
```

I have the following line in my ~/.bashrc

```
  export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/bcddivad/code/ros;
  source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash
  export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/bcddivad/code/ros/turtle_tf:/opt/ros/electric/stacks;
```

How can I solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37063/problem-with-rosmaking-mrpt_common-package/) by [bcddivad](https://answers.ros.org/users/2223/bcddivad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2012-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is wrong and the lines in your .bashrc look pretty messy. First you set the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to the directory `/home/bcddivad/code/ros`, then you overwrite it and it is probably set to `/opt/ros/electric/stacks` and then you overwrite it again by setting it to `/home/bcddivad/code/ros/turtle_tf:/opt/ros/electric/stacks` which removes `/home/bcddivad/code/ros`.

In general, this kind of problems can easily be avoided by using something like [rosws](http://ros.org/wiki/rosws). Also have a look at [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/36784/how-to-install-a-stack-and-package-manually-in/?answer=36787#post-id-36787) for a quick way to get things set up cleanly using rosws.

A quick fix in your case would be to edit ~/.bashrc and replace the three lines you posted by:

```
source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$HOME/code/ros:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

That way, you use everything set up in /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash and you add $HOME/code/ros and all its subdirectories. You can verify the current ROS_PACKAGE_PATH by executing `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0